# Jolt Transformation to "unpivot" repeating columns into nested JSON array

Tags: json, jolt

My source data is a huge flatten CSV which contains data that I'd like to normalise and store in a number of separate database tables.  I'm wondering if I can use a JOLT transformation to alter the structure of my CSV data which I've already a flat JSON object.

For example, the object below has two 'parent' rows and three repeating pairs of columns which are the 'child' rows:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "zzz",
  "code_1": "abc",
  "date_1": "2021-01-01",
  "code_2": "def",
  "date_2": "2021-01-02",
  "code_3": "ghi",
  "date_3": "2021-01-03"
}
```

Can I use JOLT to generate the output:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "zzz",
  "codes": [
    {
      "code": "abc",
      "date": "2021-01-01"
    },
    {
      "code": "def",
      "date": "2021-01-02"
    },
    {
      "code": "ghi",
      "date": "2021-01-03"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've had a play around with the [Jolt Playground](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com), but as yet I've not found something which could achieve this goal.

Any hints, tips, or pointers welcome.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I'm getting closer, with the following spec and output.  My codes and dates are in different objects however:

spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "identifier": "id",
      "name": "name",
      "code*": "codes[].code",
      "date*": "codes[].date"
    }
  }
]
```

output:

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "zzz",
  "codes" : [ {
    "code" : "abc"
  }, {
    "date" : "2021-01-01"
  }, {
    "code" : "def"
  }, {
    "date" : "2021-01-02"
  }, {
    "code" : "ghi"
  }, {
    "date" : "2021-01-03"
  } ]
}
```

(Edit: corrected the required output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformations twice as the elements are grouped under common numbered keys by **_1**,**_2**,**_3** in the first step, and then remove keys of those objects while nesting them within **codes** list such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "code*": { "@": "&(0,1).code" },
      "date*": { "@": "&(0,1).date" }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "_*": "codes[]",
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is excellent and does exactly as I need, though I think you accidentally omitted the "_" prefix before the &'s the first spec? In my file I have this pattern repeating a number of times (diagnosis, treatment etc..), so I can use this approach and prefix each of the groups with an appropriate identifier for conversion into an array by the second spec, and it should still work regardless of how many repeating columns there are!  Brilliant.

Comment: Thank you too @Mark ; No, intentionally left as they're, eg. no need to put underscore, except to filter within the second spec.